# Calculating error in PCA

Tags: linear-algebra, pca

I have a question about a result which I did not expect when doing PCA.

I have successfully calculated the principal components using reference data, and then as a check to ensure that what's going on is what I think is going on, I've projected the reference data onto the entire basis of its eigenfucntions (kept all components) and then transformed back, (this is in python, so it's pca.fit(ref_data) followed by ref_data_transform =pca.transform.(ref_data) followed by pca.inverse_transform(ref_data_transform) I get the exact same data. This is not a surprise.

What is also not a surprise is that as I choose fewer and fewer principle components, the point to point difference between the original data and that which has been projected onto a smaller basis and then projected back increases. That is, if you plot the original data and "filtered" data, it looks different, with the difference increasing as you reduce the size of the subspace onto which you're projecting. I can capture the difference between each data point in a vector called, say, difference_vec.

What IS a surprise (to me at least) is that when I sum over any column of difference_vec it always equals zero. That is, while the actual differences between any original data point and the corresponding one filtered by some number of principal components grow larger as I project onto a smaller and smaller subspace, the TOTAL error is always zero.

I very much appreciate any insight that one my have into if I'm making some mistake here and if not, why this erstwhile "projection induced error" metric doesn't work.

Thanks.

Comment: Very neat question, I’m not sure why `sum(ref_data - inv_data)` yields zero—likely a question for math.stackexchange.com. When comparing matrixes like this, I use a matrix norm, i.e., `numpy.linalg.norm` (which will pick the Frobenius norm). In this case, `norm(ref_data - inv_data)` will definitely not be zero. But it’s still an interesting question why `sum` is zero.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `ref_data` and what I’ll call `inv_data = pca.inverse_transform(pca.transform(ref_data))` both have the same mean (taken along the second dimension, i.e., averaging over samples).

To see this, take a look at the code for [`transform`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/decomposition/base.py#L101):

```
transform = lambda X: dot(X - mu, V.T)
```

whereas [`inverse_transform`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/14031f6/sklearn/decomposition/base.py#L138) can be defined as:

```
inverse_transform = lambda X: dot(X, V) + mu
```

where `mu` is the mean of `ref_data` and `V` are the first `N` eigenvectors of `covariance(ref_data)`.

So if you follow the chain of data and its mean:

1. `ref_data` with mean `mu`;
2. `transform(ref_data)` has mean 0 (see the equivalent definition above: `X-mu` has zero mean, then projecting the result linearly onto some coordinate reference only rotates/shears/flips those zero-mean points, doesn’t alter their mean;
3. Finally, `inv_data = inverse_transform(transform(ref_data))` adds `mu` back so it has `mu`-mean;

you see that `ref_data` and `inv_data` both have mean `mu`.

Finally, `sum(ref_data - inv_data)` can be seen as `sum(mean(ref_data - inv_data) * num_samples)`, which by linearity simplifies to `sum(mu - mu)`, which is 0.

That’s a lot of words, sorry, but the idea, now that I see it, is really simple. As I mentioned in my comment, in cases like this you want to use a matrix norm, like the Frobenius norm, to measure a distance between two matrixes, not just `sum(A - B)` !

---

Sample code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

ref_data = np.random.randn(20, 3)
pca = PCA(n_components=1)
pca.fit(ref_data)
trans_data = pca.transform(ref_data)
inv_data = pca.inverse_transform(trans_data)

np.mean(inv_data, 0)   # array([ 0.03664149,  0.51348007,  0.0360179 ])
np.mean(ref_data, 0)   # array([ 0.03664149,  0.51348007,  0.0360179 ])
np.mean(trans_data, 0) # array([ -2.49800181e-17]) meanwhile ...
np.sum(inv_data - ref_data) # -1.3877787807814457e-15 !
```

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks very much for the insight! I assume that as I keep fewer and fewer components, the Frobenius norm will get larger and larger, correct? Does this make it a useful way to measure deviance (for, say, anomaly detection) using PCA? That is, can I use the norm of (Ref_data-projecteced_test_data) as a way to determine how "far" from the PCs the test data is? Thanks again for your advice.

Comment: “as I keep fewer and fewer components, the Frobenius norm will get larger and larger” — I’d say it slightly differently: the norm shouldn’t decrease as you use fewer components. It may plateau, that is, if you have low-rank data, then the singular values will taper off to 0, and so the norm might stop growing larger too. (I used a lot of jargon here, if this is confusing, let me know, I can clarify with a code example.)

Comment: Yes you can try using PCA for anomaly detection. The problem with PCA/ICA/etc. is that they can only capture linear features, so things like occlusions, outliers, etc., in your test data can really be problematic. So people have developed [“robust PCA” (see references therein)](http://people.ee.duke.edu/~lcarin/LRS_09.pdf)—much more computationally burdensome but more useful for anomaly detection. Still, maybe your data is linear, worth a try .

Comment: Is it the case that, for whitened PCs, will the Frobenius norm be useful as a metric for anomaly detection?It appears to give overall information regarding the differences between the projected reference and projected test matrices, but is there something more specific? Namely, if I sum the components of each column of the projected test data, does this sum represent the distance of the test vector in PC space from the center of the hypersphere? That sounds like a way to determine which of the projected eigenstates are anomalous (given some distance threshold) rather than the whole batch.

Comment: I would guess that the Frobenius norm gives a measure of the variability in the test data that is *not* captured by the principal vectors. I’m not sure if there’s any way to tell *which* principal vector is somehow “being violated” by some test data, but it might be worth a try.